# How to allow customers to input a text as a product variation *and* charge per character?

Tags: plugins, php, woocommerce-offtopic

I'm looking for a way in Woocommerce to add a product variation for customers that will allow them to put in their name/custom word(s) up to a certain character limit and the additional price will be calculated based on the number of characters in that input.

Ideally there will be a set price for a certain number of characters and then an additional fee for any characters beyond that (e.g. £x.xx for up to 5 characters, +£y.yy per character with a maximum of 10 characters).

Any code/plugin free/paid solutions welcomed.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have been working with a plugin called [TM Extra Product Options](http://codecanyon.net/item/woocommerce-extra-product-options/7908619) and I am fairly sure you could achieve your goals using that. It isn't the prettiest plugin from a UI perspective, but it has a lot of functionality and good support if you use their forums.

You could use a select box for number of characters and then set a **conditional field** to appear when they make a choice in the characters select box.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks @johncarter for the information - I have been looking at that plugin but it suffers from not being actually clear on its exact functionality :( I will give it a go however!

Comment: Eventually I bought this plugin and it worked for me :) apologies for the tardiness in accepting your answer!